# Getting notification on built dependencies exceeding a certain size using Maven

Tags: maven, jar, build, dependencies, size

I am using Maven to build a large project with multiple dependencies. I want to build a jar including all dependencies, therefore this jar is very likely to be big. There is also a high chance for this project to be modified in the future, this means more dependencies to be included.

I am currently working on refactoring the dependencies to reduce the size of the final jar.

What I would like to have is a way to get notified if any dependency in my final jar is exceeding a size S. For now, most of the dependencies included are smaller than S size, but if in the future, a new dependency is added, I want to get notified if its size is too big.

I have already looked at Maven Enforcer Plugin and was able to make the build fail if my final jar is larger than a certain size but it is not really  what I want.

Many thanks,
Carca

Comment: If the enforcer cannot help, you might need to create your own plugin, which is anyway interesting to do.

Comment: Why is it too big? And what is in your opinion too big?

Comment: I should not really have used the term "too big" because I don't have a particular size I aim for. The thing is I know the size of this jar can be reduced and I want to reduce it as much as I can.

It is big because it contains over 500 dependencies.